# Error querying channels: identity 'admin' isn't enrolled, or loaded

Tags: visual-studio, docker, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

Installed VSCode
installed IBM BLOCKCHAIN PLATFORM EXTENSION
While starting the local fabric getting error

> [10/31/2019 2:41:30 PM] [INFO]  rem Join peer0.org1.example.com to the
>   channel.
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:30 PM] [INFO]  docker exec -e
>   "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e
>   "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp"
>   fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b
>   mychannel.block
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:30 PM] [INFO] )  [10/31/2019 2:41:31 PM] [INFO]
>   2019-10-31 09:11:31.323 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001
>   Endorser and orderer connections initialized
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:31 PM] [INFO] 2019-10-31 09:11:31.626 UTC
>   [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 0
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:32 PM] [INFO] 2019-10-31 09:11:32.347 UTC
>   [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer
>   connections initialized
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:32 PM] [INFO] 2019-10-31 09:11:32.386 UTC
>   [channelCmd] update -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted channel update
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:33 PM] [INFO] 2019-10-31 09:11:33.098 UTC
>   [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer
>   connections initialized
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:34 PM] [INFO] 2019-10-31 09:11:34.784 UTC
>   [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted proposal
>   to join channel
>
> [10/31/2019 2:41:37 PM] [ERROR] **Error connecting to environment
>   local_fabric: Error: Error querying channels: identity 'admin' isn't
>   enrolled, or loaded**

Comment: Might be worth tearing down the local fabric by right clicking `Local Fabric` and selecting Teardown Fabric Runtime and trying to start it again.

Comment: i did tear down fabric, stop fabric also.still getting error

Comment: think you need to raise an issue at https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues
include all the logs, plus info on your environment (eg OS version, Docker etc)